# Is np.ones(n) a row vector or column vector?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Is np.ones(n) a row vector or column vector? I am so confused. If we are not sure whether it is a row or column vector, how can I use it for matrix computation?

Comment: Yes or no!  It is a 1d array.  A (1,n) shape is better described as a row vector, and (n,1) as a column vector.  But usually in `numpy` we don't need that extra size 1 dimension.

Comment: You specify the shape as an argument. So you can create whichever kind of vector you want.

Comment: And you can reshape it to the other with `np.reshape((-1,n))`, or `np.reshape((n,-1))`

Comment: @MarkSetchell Reshaping an array known to have `n` elements to shape `(-1,n)` or `(n, -1)` seems like something you would do to confuse somebody new to numpy :).